# Can I set a custom GeoIP Library location when configuring nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx with the `--with-http_geoip_module`, which requires the [GeoIP Library](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c). I've installed the GeoIP library in a nonstandard location, so NGINX can't find it when looking for it. Is there a way to point NGINX to my custom location?

NGINX looks for it in `/usr/local/`, `/usr/pkg/`, and `/opt/local/` by default. The code is [here](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/auto/lib/geoip/conf?v=nginx-1.12.0). There is also code for the `auto/feature` call that actually tests each location [here](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/auto/feature?v=nginx-1.12.0).

Thank you!